# Magento products sometimes in categories sometimes not $product = Mage::registry('current_product');

Tags: magento

When using,

```
$category = Mage::registry('current_category');
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
```

To see if we are on a product or category page some product pages return as just `$product` and some return as `$product` and `$category`.

Both products appear to be set up identically and in the same single category. It does not appear to matter how we enter / which navigation route we take to the product page.

So to sum up, we appear to have 2 types of product page
Products in categories and products not in categories.

If both are assigned to and show up in a category correctly, 
What is the difference and where is it set?

To calrify

```
product  1    
$category = Mage::registry('current_category'); -- false
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); -- true

product  2    
$category = Mage::registry('current_category'); -- true
$product = Mage::registry('current_product'); -- true
```

What is the difference and where is it set?

Comment: Question is not clear..Put a clear questions

Answer (score 0):

If I understood corectly what you're asking.

When you go to a category page:

You have the controller `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController` with the method `protected function _initCatagory()` that will save in a registry key the current category: `Mage::register('current_category', $category);`

When you go to a product page:

You have the controller `Mage_Catalog_ProductController` with the method `protected function _initProduct()`, here the helper `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product` is called with the method `public function initProduct($productId, $controller, $params = null)`.
This method registers both the product and it's parent category (if it has one - category_id sent as a parameter in GET via route match - url rewrites):

```
if ($categoryId) {
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
        $product->setCategory($category);
        Mage::register('current_category', $category);
    }

    // Register current data and dispatch final events
    Mage::register('current_product', $product);
```

Comment: Both products are identical until i call Mage::registry('current_category');  from the product page, both have the same category settings and show as the same so why the difference where is it set ?

Comment: Look in the admin, under Catalog > URL redirects and search for both products, I think one of them has a path like `catalog/product/view/$id` and the other has something like `catalog/product/view/$id/category/$category_id`

Comment: Both have entries for  catalog/product/view/$id/category/$category_id and catalog/product/view/$id so identical bar product id

Comment: Ok, but I think that for one of them you go on the link that also has the category and for the other you go on the link that only has the product.

Comment: Both Navigation routes produce the same issue , I have tried direct url, from search and from cat select and still same issue and both appear the same.